# Left aligning a caption

Tags: floats

Captions are usually center aligned if one line or justified if more than one line.

I would like to left align / justify some captions, even if one-liner.

I read some instructions about the captions package but these seems to apply to all captions of all floats, while I want to do that only for the captions of one kind of float.

By the way, a solution I can apply manually to the few floats with captions I want left align is fine.

Comment: Caption can also configure locally. If you use `\begin{figure}[....] \captionsetup{...} ... \end{figure}` that caption setup only applies to that particular figure.

Comment: You mention "one kind of float". Which one?

Comment: @Mico I used the package float to create my own float environment to distinguish among different kind of figures and to list separately in list of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Centered caption text}
\label{fig:center}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false} % <---
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Left aligned caption text}
\label{fig:center}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

Comment: the line marked seems the key I was missing. I'll try asap

Comment: @unlikely, since answer solve your problem you may consider to upvote it and even accept it (by clicking on the up-triangle and check mark at top left side of answer :-) (as far as I see so far you not accept any from received answers; ar no one fulfil your expectation?